# How to select non null columns in a single row result?

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to select all non null values in a row in oracle ?

Suppose `table A (id, aa, ab, ac)` has `(1, 12, '', '')(2, '', 3, 4);`

```
select * from A where id = 1;
```

gives the entire row.

But i want to select all the fields that are not null.

In this case ->

```
where id = 1 should return (1, 12)
and where id = 2 should return (2, 3, 4)
```

EDIT :

Why would I want this ? Imagine having a table that has about a hundred fields.
With most of them null for almost every row.
I want a view that shows me only non null fields.
I know that this cant be done for a set of rows. That would be inconsistent.
But, whenever I can single out a row using its primary key, shouldnt this be possible ?
(Without having to explicitly rule out null value fields using case / other constructs )

Comment: It's not possible - or it is at least really complicated. What do you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: you cannot have select * return a limited column set like that (at least not efficiently), and if you did `select * from A where id in (1, 2)` then what? return all columns with some rows null still? you could concatenate all non-null columns using case statements so that they all came out as one column `case when aa is not null then aa end ||','||case when ab is not null...` etc. but you may run into issues with string lengths. or you could have an array return of (name,val) for each row eg `1,myarr(mycol('AA',12))` and `2,myarr(mycol('AB',3),mycol('AC',4)` to solve this.would that be of use?

Answer (score 2):

This is bogus.  The same query will return different result sets depending on the internal state of the data, not the query itself.  And how is the client program supposed to figure out whether the second column in the projection is `A.aa` or `A.ab`  or even `A.ac`?

There are a variety of possible solutions, using some combination of dynamic SQL, pipelined functions  or ref cursors.  But it really depends on how the calling program will consume the results.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, such a structure is against [*Relational Data Model*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) since you're asking for different tuples in the same projection.

So, a regular sql result-set is probably not the best way to hold such data...
Instead use XML:

```
select xmlElement
           (
             "Row",
             XMLForest(id, aa, ab, ac)
           )
 from A
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f162/4)

Comment: It's a very nice idea - and if XMLForest(*) would work it'd actually solve this tricky problem. But I just get ORA-00931 - an internal error (meaning this is an Oracle bug) and in my experience everything related to XML and especially JSON is super buggy in Oracle. Maybe in 8 another years haha

Answer (score 1):

One way that you can find out what fields do not have `null` values is to `UNPIVOT` the data.  *This however displays the data as a column a not a row*

```
select id, col, value
from
(
  select id, aa value, 'aa' col
  from tablea
  union all
  select id, ab value, 'ab' col
  from tablea
  union all
  select id, ac value, 'ac' col
  from tablea
) src
where id = 2
  and value is not null;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59d5d/9)

If you sample data is:

```
create table tableA
(
  id number,
  aa number,
  ab number,
  ac number
);

insert into tablea values(1, 12, null, null);
insert into tablea values(2, null, 3, 4);
```

And you search for `id = 1` the result will be displayed as:

```
| ID | COL | VALUE |
--------------------
|  1 |  aa |    12 |
```

If you search for `id=2` then the result is:

```
| ID | COL | VALUE |
--------------------
|  2 |  ab |     3 |
|  2 |  ac |     4 |
```